# H.265 decoding: segmentation fault

Tags: python, parsing, video, hevc, h.265

I use HM 14.0 as reference software.

Using config file, a frame is decomposed in many packets of MTU 500 bytes.

I deleted packets from an H.265 bitstream (i kept vps, sps, pps packets) and when I try to decode the produced bitstream, i get **segmantation fault**.

I post an example of the produced bitstream file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-CFx75Ro7vGenJ5SU40cVBhaWc/edit?usp=sharing). This bitstream file has 3% less packets than the original.

The annexBbytecountStatic is working properly and parses the new bitstream file.

Any ideas to solve the problem? Did I forget any important packet?

Comment: Can't download the file currently, but one thing to consider when deleting packets: The reference software is not set up for this, it assumes a valid bitstream and can't handle errors. Do you delete full frames or just packets?

Comment: @Bastian Oh ok! No, just packets. Do you have any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: @Bastian Or there the ability to delete a packet and input an empty one, in order the decoder not to "aware" any lost packet?

Comment: I don't think there is an easy solution to this. The easiest thing to do would be to just drop the complete frame, if a packet in the frame is missing, but as far as i know, there is no nal unit size information in the bitstream, which is why you can't tell whether a nal unit is complete or not. Inputting empty packets also won't work: the CABAC engine does not just expect a specific number of bits, it's much more complicated. Unfortunately, there is no exception-based error handling implemented. The decoder just crashes if the bitstream is not valid, e.g. because of segmentation faults.

Comment: If you delete nal units or access units, that's not as difficult to handle.

Comment: @Bastian OK thank you! So, do you propose me to delete access unit aka all nal units for decoding a whole frame?

Comment: @Bastian I want to perform packet loss in a bitstream for my phd research and I want to achieve it as soon as possible...

Comment: yes, i'd recommend just that. There are of course techniques to partly reconstruct frames where parts of the corresponding bitstream are missing, but that's much work to implement, and probably not too simple. If you drop access units, you just have to take care when parts of the corresponding frames are referenced for inter frame prediction, and react to this somehow. you can of course drop the other frame as well, or to some error-concealment (interpainting).

Comment: @Bastian35022 As I can see now, unfortunately that is not an option! I have to implement packet loss in H.265 bitstream. Is to replicate the previous packet in the place of lost packet?

Comment: @Bastian35022 Or can i keep the nal unit header and slice segment and put null payload?

Comment: You can of course try, but i am quite sure that this won't work. You will have to implement some error handling into the reference decoder. I am not sure at what precise points to do this though. If you use container formats (like MP4), there are other options to find frames where some data, i.e. packets, was lost, and then drop the complete frame.

Comment: "Or can i keep the nal unit header and slice segment and put null payload?" – i guess that's not typical packet loss behaviour, right? Besides if you only have the nal unit header and slice segment header, and no payload, you can't reconstruct a single pixel of the slice, so you can just drop the complete pay unit instead.

Comment: @Bastian35022 No that's not typical packet loss behavior. I want typical packet loss behavior but as far I can't have it, I must find any other similar behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the fact that the HM decoder can't handle a bitstream having lost packets, I use libde265 decoder, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19298219/how-to-decode-hevc-files-to-yuv/21934500#21934500). Libde265 can decode bitstreams having lost packets.